# Parse json string by JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json

I want parse json string into c# object by JavaScriptSerializer, my json object looks like below:

```
[{
            "text" : "aaaa",
            "cls" : "folder",
            "checked" : false,
            "isconsign" : false,
            "myid" : "catalog_1",
            "id" : "catalog_1",
            "children" : [{
                "text" : "vvvv",
                "cls" : "file",
                "leaf" : true,
                "checked" : false,
                "disabled" : true,
                "myid" : "4456",
                "id" : "input_4456"
            }, {
                "text" : "sdf",
                "cls" : "file",
                "leaf" : true,
                "checked" : false,
                "disabled" : true,
                "myid" : "4465",
                "id" : "input_4465"
}]
```

But when I declare my C# object like below:

```
public class TreeViewItem
{
    public string text {get;set;}
    public string cls {get;set;}
    public bool disabled {get;set;}
    public bool isconsign {get;set;}
    public bool leaf {get;set;}
    public string myid {get;set;}
    public string id {get;set;}
    public bool checked {get;set;}
}
```

The c# compiler tell me can not declare checked in object or struct.
Now, I can't change the checked property in the string send from client, so is there any solution (something like alias) to resolve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`checked` is a keyword here. Obviously, its not going to accept it as a varaible.

Try using it like this : `public bool @checked {get;set;}`

Use that `@` sign just at the start of your variable name and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you try using Newtonsoft.Json

you will find that it is easier to handle your Jason objects

your code will be like this

```
TreeViewItem defaultCallResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TreeViewItem>(return_value);
```

but first you need to adjust your Classes by creating other class named `children` holding all the properties retrieved form your request under `children` then adjust your class `TreeViewItem`  to contain list of `children`

Answer (score 0):

@Hussein Khalil - The `json` object doesn't look similar to the `C#` type specified.
The deserialization might not work properly.